# Vertex Ran Too Long on Preparing in ADLA

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a U-SQL script which is running across a number of JSON files stored in a Data Lake, when I run the script against a single file everything works well, however opening this up to run against all of the files I get the following error every single time and the job never gets past the 'Preparing' stage (where is spends around 30 minutes):

```
System: E_SYSTEM_COMPILER_COMPILERINTERNALERROR
SEVERITY: ERROR
DESCRIPTION: Compilation failed due to internal system error.
MESSAGE: Compilation failed due to internal system error. (255)
DETAILS: Compilation failed for Deep.; JobId: 6ddc1049-c064-46d4-    b31f-1073ffd2cc99; Duration: 00:31:10.4668250; Exit Code: 255; Configuration: kobo_vnext_signed_5395848; Runtime: kobo_vnext_signed_5395848; Output: Deleted file D:\data\CCS\jobs\6ddc1049-c064-46d4-b31f-1073ffd2cc99_v0\securityInfo.
Deleted file D:\data\CCS\jobs\6ddc1049-c064-46d4-b31f-1073ffd2cc99_v0\jobEncryptionKey.
Server Version: 10.2.2.0
Client Version: 10.2.2.0
Target: Cluster
Stat: FetchReal
SkipPath: False
Syntax Parsing finished.
Resource Resolution finished.
Input/Output Resolution finished.
HandleCodeBehind finished.
Wait until structured stream metadata loading end finished.
Binder Pass finished.
Semantic Analyzer finished.
Error Reporter finished.
OptTree Generator finished.

--==== CQO Optimization ====--
Traceflag 608 is ON
Traceflag 551 is ON
Traceflag 402 is ON
Traceflag 550 is ON
Traceflag 21 is ON
Traceflag 552 is ON
Traceflag 554 is ON
Traceflag 515 is ON
Traceflag 534 is ON
Traceflag 541 is ON
Traceflag 435 is ON
Traceflag 106 is ON
Traceflag 62 is ON
Traceflag 571 is ON
Traceflag 514 is ON
Traceflag 568 is ON
Traceflag 569 is ON
Traceflag 203 is ON
Traceflag 546 is ON
Traceflag 562 is ON
Traceflag 563 is ON
Traceflag 505 is ON
Traceflag 506 is ON
Traceflag 542 is ON
Polaris scale up query execution is not enabled
Timer[CQO - Init] = 0.0172413 s
Timer[CQO - CopyIn] = 0.154232 s
Timer[CQO - Search - Init] = 0.000229223 s
Timer[CQO - Search - NNF] = 0.0124772 s
Timer[CQO - Search - PreOptimization] = 0.000576905 s
Pruning partitions and streamsets
Simplifying relational tree

Timer[CQO - Total] = 749.761 s
CQO: Optimization failed.


;

RESOLUTION
```

On the Diagnostics tab in VS2017 I also see:

```
Vertex ran too long: 00:31:10
```

What could cause this? I'm struggling somewhat to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: I had/have the same problem when using queries against a large set of (small) json files. See https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/13389741-support-running-jobs-against-many-small-blobs-10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try the FileSet Option (https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2017/2017_04_24/USQL_Release_Notes_2017_04_24.md#input-file-set-scales-orders-of-magnitudes-better-opt-in-statement-is-now-provided)

I ran into a similar problem a couple of weeks ago. I first solved the problem by increasing the number of AUs. But then, using

```
 SET @@FeaturePreviews = "FileSetV2Dot5:on";
```

helped reduce the compilation time while using a smaller amount of AUs

Comment: Great... I am glad it helped

Comment: Now we have this feature preview as well which worked for me: 
 SET @@FeaturePreviews = "InputFileGrouping:on";

Comment: It is still not working for me. Every time it fails after running it for almost 10 hours on 2 AU. My input file size is 21 GB and that is stored on blob storage. It is failing in extract stage where vertex is 1 - 
Error : Vertex failed with a fail-fast error
Description: Vertex failure triggered quick job abort. Vertex failed: SV1_Extract_Partition[0] with error: Process execution time is too long.